# "npm install" only those modules that arent already installed globally

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, package

Is there anyway to install dependencies which are not installed globally? For example: i got gulp installed globally, then I have some app with gulp inside *package.json*. When i run:

```
npm install
```

it will download and install gulp in node_modules in my app root folder, even if it is already in node.js global.

It would be nice, because I made template for new projects, with lots of dependecies. I dont want to keep over 20000 files in each project root folder...

Answer (score 0):

Gulp is actually required to be installed **both** locally and globally.

`require` can only find locally installed modules. Globally installed modules are generally required for command line. But if you have a `require` statement in your file (which it is in case of gulpfile.js) it will need that module be installed locally.

A possible solution for not having to keep same dependencies in two places could be to put them in a parent `node_modules` folder

```
My Projects
    node_modules
        gulp
    Project A
        ...
    Project B
        ...
```

Since `require` looks for modules in parent directories successively from current level this shall work.

Comment: Thats not true. Everything works fine since I use NODE_PATH system variable pointing to global node_modules folder (yep, Windows). I dont have node_modules anywhere near my project folder, and Im able to run gulp tasks in project folder. But I want to be able to move my projects between computers, and use it in the same manner. In default behaviour `npm install` will parse package.json and install all deps in subfolder (local, not global). Is there any way to change it? Typing `npm install -g` is copying my project to global folder, not installing modules from package.json globally :/